# Need insight on how to fix my Python prime number list generator

Tags: python, math

I'm new to programming, and to practice learning Python, I'm trying to write a program that will test which numbers in a range from `(2, n-1)` are prime, by testing if there are any factors num is divisible by between `2` and `sqrt(n)`.

For the most part, the prime list is pretty accurate, but for some reason the squares of primes >= 11 make it through the loop. The `for i in range` part of the loop should be filtering them out. I have a feeling it has to do wih how I ordered the `if-statements`, or maybe how I indented everything, but I can't quite figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

I also realize I could just keep adding `num % 11 == 0` or `num % 13 == 0` to line 7, but that kinda defeats the purpose of the program automating this for me.

Also, I know I could just find a million other Python prime checkers, but I'm trying to figure out where I'm going wrong here so I can improve. Thank you!!!

```
n = 362
prime = []
def prime_check(lst=range(2,n)):
  for num in lst:
    if num == 1 or num == 2 or num == 3 or num == 5 or num == 7:
      prime.append(num)
    if num % 2 == 0 or num % 3 == 0 or num % 5 == 0:
      continue
    for i in range(5, int(sqrt(n)+1), 2):
      if num % i == 0:
          continue
    else:
      prime.append(num)
  print(prime)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import math
n = 362
prime = []
def prime_check(lst=range(2,n)):
    for num in lst:
        if num == 2 or num == 3 or num == 5 or num == 7:
            prime.append(num)
            continue
        if num % 2 == 0 or num % 3 == 0 or num % 5 == 0:
            continue
        flag = 0
        for i in range(5, int(math.sqrt(num)+1), 2):
            if num % i == 0:
                flag=1
                break
        if flag == 0:
            prime.append(num)
    return prime
print(prime_check())
```

You had one issue in the logic. The `flag` ensures a prime is added only once.

Note: I also got confused. The logic that you have wrote is wrong. That is exactly why the number 121 which is just 11x11 gets into the prime list.
Note2: One portion I wrote wrong earlier regarding `else` part. (Corrected due to @Kelly Bundy)

```
def prime_check(lst=range(2,n)):
    for num in lst:
        flag = 0
        if num % 2 == 0:
             continue
        for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(num)+1), 2):
            if num % i == 0:
                flag=1
                break
        if flag == 0:
            prime.append(num)
    return prime
```

Note: `1` is non-prime.

My earlier answer and even now the current answer, avoided `for-else`. Personally, I avoid it explicitly - using such syntactic constructs not only makes it less readable for me but the time to understand such things in large codebase is really difficult.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I see the error in my logic and I understand how you fixed it! I appreciate the help, because not only did your changes fix the squares appearing, but it also helped with the duplicates that were popping up too!!!

Answer (score 1):

A few remarks:

- 1 is **not** a prime number.
- I don't really see a good reason to make a special case for 2,3,5,7 in your code.
- `prime` and `n` should be local variables of the function, not outside variables that are referred from inside.
- You should probably add a check to filter out negative numbers, which are not prime.
- `math.sqrt` is a function to compute a precise floating-point approximation of a square root. But we're dealing with integers here. We only care about the integer part of the square root. There is [`math.isqrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt) for that.
- Since you immediately break out of the loop when variable `flag` is set to 1, and then you never reuse `flag` after that, then you don't really need variable `flag` at all.

Furthermore, your problem can be decomposed into two distinct tasks:

- Test if a given number `num` is a prime;
- Using this test, filter list `lst` to only keep the primes.

When programming, it is always good to identify distinct tasks, and write one function per task. I'll decompose your code into two functions: one function `is_prime` and one function `filter_primes`.

```py
import math

def is_prime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False # negative numbers, 0, and 1, are not prime
    for d in range(2, math.isqrt(num)+1):
        if num % d == 0:
            return False
    return True

# OR ALTERNATIVELY
# def is_prime(num):
#     return num >= 2 and not any(num % d == 0 for d in range(2, math.isqrt(num)+1))

def filter_primes(lst):
    primes = []
    for num in lst:
        if is_prime(num):
            primes.append(num)
    return primes

# OR ALTERNATIVELY
# def filter_primes(lst):
#     return list(filter(is_prime, lst))

print( filter_primes(range(362)) )
# [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41,
#  43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97
#  01, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149,
#  151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197,
#  199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257,
#  263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313,
#  317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359]
```

Answer (score -3):

You should use the correct root and use `break` and not treat 7 inconsistently.

Fixed code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVBBasMwELzrFXMJWNSUxMalBPySUorjrGuRaKXKyiGvd1dyXJxLdZrZ0cys5O9xdFy/@zDPQ3AWtosjjPUuREw/ISrFaFG/VcoHY0nwx6c604BMv/qR@ktxnWIbOv6moipZ66MCBhfANwvDEDVNADPkUdvigIcsuNrgeoObxYSl6bXznvhciKi3YTvxy@X9atxJxjNvMl/DesfR8I0yTUuatOKyfFMKjkV6du55OegSlV6tf43mKTGdU6DukjldJ/pvcZlJRVa0UttP1PP8Cw)):

```
from math import sqrt

n = 362
prime = []
def prime_check(lst=range(2,n)):
  for num in lst:
    if num == 1 or num == 2 or num == 3 or num == 5:
      prime.append(num)
    if num % 2 == 0 or num % 3 == 0 or num % 5 == 0:
      continue
    for i in range(5, int(sqrt(num)+1), 2):
      if num % i == 0:
          break
    else:
      prime.append(num)
  print(prime)

prime_check()
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359]
```

Comment: Same answer as what? And where do you see 121 in my output? It's not there.